# How to use plt.text() function to type special symbols into a plot produced by python3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, text, latex, symbolic-math

I am trying to type a text (which includes some astrophysical symbols like solar mass and Hubble's Parameter) inside an empty figure in a python script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(4)
frame = plt.gca()
frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
A = 2
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4 
plt.text(0.05, 0.05, r'$R_{200m}$={:.0f} kpc physical \n\n $M_{200m}$={:.3e} $h^{-1} M_{\sun}$ \n\n\n\n x={:.0f} \n\n $M_{DM}$={:.3e} $h^{-1} M_{\odot}$'.format(A, B, C, D), size=20)
plt.show()
```

I am receiving the following error message after running the script with `python3 example.py` :

```
  File "exam.py", line 12, in <module>
      plt.text(0.05, 0.05, r'$R_{200m}$={:.0f} kpc physical \n\n $M_{200m}$={:.3e} $h^{-1} M_{\sun}$ \n\n\n\n x={:.0f} \n\n
  $M_{DM}$={:.3e} $h^{-1} M_{\odot}$'.format(A, B, C, D), size=20) 
  KeyError: '200m'
```

I don't know how to make LateX typings possible inside a python script?

---

Attached is the snapshot of the error message when running a code in which I am using the same format as the one suggested in the answer. I am running this code on an anaconda in which only python3.5 has been installed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your `plt.text...` line with the following:

```
plt.text(0.05, 0.05, '$R_{{200m}}$={:.0f} kpc physical \n\n $M_{{200m}}$={:.3e} $h^{{-1}} M_\u2609$ \n\n\n\n x={:.0f} \n\n $M_{{DM}}$={:.3e} $h^{{-1}} M_{{\odot}}$'.format(A, B, C, D), size=20)
```

I just:

1. replaced `{\sun}` with `\u2609`, see [How to do the astronomical symbol "\sun" in PyX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486778/how-to-do-the-astronomical-symbol-sun-in-pyx).
2. doubled the `{` of each LateX one, so the `format` method won't put its parameters in it.
3. removed the `r` before the string so that the `\n`s will affect.

[image]

Comment: Thank You, that is interesting.

Comment: Can I make the text $kpc physical$ in italic form?

Comment: Thanks, Just figured that out: ${{kpc \/physical}}$

Comment: Hi Ophir, when running the same code under anaconda python 3.5, I am receiving the following error message: ValueError: h^{-1} M_\u2609 Expected {| ...|... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |... |} (at char 10), (line: 1, col: 11)    I am not sure if some packages are needed given that only python is installed for me by the IT person on a remote machine.

Comment: I didn't understand if you have anaconda or just python

Comment: I just have pure python packages on top of anaconda without extra packages that are needed but missing. I just  want to know what are they that are causing such an error.

Comment: I just added the full screen of most of the error message I am receiving in the line of code in which I am using the suggestions you made except that I am running the same code on a different machine in which only Python is installed.

Comment: I get your error only if I use python 2.7. With python 3.5.1 there is no error.